# task fields are not displaying value in LWC, which is used in partner community

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, api, ui

I have created LWC, which is having controller to fetch task records from apex controller. but it is again giving me same error "**Object Task is not supported in UI API**". can any one please let me now what is wrong in this code.

js file:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getSObjectValue }                    from '@salesforce/apex';
import GetTaskRecords                         from '@salesforce/apex/FetchTaskLWCController.GetTaskRecords';
import task_Object                            from '@salesforce/schema/Task';
import Task_Assigned_To                       from '@salesforce/schema/Task.OwnerId';
import Task_Status                            from '@salesforce/schema/Task.Status';
import Task_Priority                          from '@salesforce/schema/Task.Priority';
import Task_Due_Date                          from '@salesforce/schema/Task.ActivityDate';
import Task_Type                              from '@salesforce/schema/Task.Type';
import Task_Related_to_Account                from '@salesforce/schema/Task.WhatId';
import Task_Subject                           from '@salesforce/schema/Task.Subject';
import Task_Comments                          from '@salesforce/schema/Task.Description';


export default class ApexWireMethodToFunction extends LightningElement {
    @api TaskRecord;
    @api recordId;
    @track tasks;
    @track error;

    taskObject = task_Object;

    @wire(GetTaskRecords, {Id: '$TaskRecord'})
    task;

    get assignedto() {
        return this.task.data ? getSObjectValue(this.task.data, Task_Assigned_To) : '';
    }
    get status() {
        return this.task.data ? getSObjectValue(this.task.data, Task_Status) : '';
    }
    get priority() {
        return this.task.data ? getSObjectValue(this.task.data, Task_Priority) : '';
    }
    get duedate() {
        return this.task.data ? getSObjectValue(this.task.data, Task_Due_Date) : '';
    }
    get type() {
        return this.task.data ? getSObjectValue(this.task.data, Task_Type) : '';
    }
    get relatedtoaccount() {
        return this.task.data ? getSObjectValue(this.task.data, Task_Related_to_Account) : '';
    }
    get subject() {
        return this.task.data ? getSObjectValue(this.task.data, Task_Subject) : '';
    }
    get comments() {
        return this.task.data ? getSObjectValue(this.task.data, Task_Comments) : '';
    }

    wiredTasks({ error, data })
    {
        if (data) 
        {
            this.tasks = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) 
        {
            this.error = error;
            this.tasks = undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

html file:

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
    <!-- Opportunity -->
      <!-- Display -->
        <template if:true={TaskRecord}>
            <lightning-record-form 
            record-id={TaskRecord}
            object-api-name={taskObject}
            >
            <!-- Messages -->
            <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
            <div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large">
            <br/>
            <!-- Fields -->
                <lightning-accordion active-section-name="A">
                    <lightning-accordion-section name="A" label="Task Details">
                        <div class="slds-grid" style="color:rgb(15, 15, 15); font-size:13px">
                            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                                <div class=" acc slds-list_horizontal slds-border_bottom">
                                    <label>Subject</label>
                                    {subject}
                                </div>
                                <div class=" acc slds-list_horizontal slds-border_bottom">
                                    <label>Status</label>
                                    {status}
                                </div>
                                <div class=" acc slds-list_horizontal slds-border_bottom">
                                    <label>Related To Account</label>
                                    {relatedtoaccount}
                                </div>
                                <div class="acc slds-border_bottom slds-list_horizontal">
                                    <label>Priority</label>
                                    {priority}
                                </div>
                                <div class="formfield slds-list_horizontal slds-border_bottom">
                                    <label>Assigned To</label>
                                    <div class="a11">{assignedto}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-2">
                                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                                    <div class="formfield slds-border_bottom slds-list_horizontal">
                                        <label>Due Date</label>
                                        {duedate}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="formfield slds-border_bottom slds-list_horizontal">
                                        <label>Type</label>
                                        {type}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="formfield slds-border_bottom slds-list_horizontal">
                                        <label>Comments</label>
                                        {comments}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </lightning-accordion-section>
                </lightning-accordion>
            </div>
            <br/>
        </lightning-record-form>
        </template>

</lightning-card>
```

js-meta.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="partnerOpportunityRecordRead">
    <apiVersion>47.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>partner Task Record Read LWC</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="TaskRecord" type="String" default="Record_ID"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Controller :

```
 public with sharing class FetchTaskLWCController
{
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Task> GetTaskRecords() 
    {
        return [SELECT Id, OwnerId, Status, Priority, ActivityDate, Type, WhatId, Subject, Description FROM Task];
    }
}
```

As task and event are unsupported objects in UI API, so took apex controller approach.

Comment: In your HTML file, I don't think you are making use of lightning-record-form, you are displaying task data using custom code. So, you should remove the lightning-record-form from your HTML code as lightning-record-form doesn't support task object.

Comment: hey avi.. have removed lightning-record-form, I can see field label but it is not showing any value

Comment: You should first check whether you have the record Id in 'TaskRecord' variable and then are you getting the task record from the apex in javascript by console logging.

Comment: @AviRai have checked it, also just to make sure I've directly passes id of record in js..still it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, from your code, I have removed some extra lines in HTML and JS files and mainly changed the apex method to return only one task in apex controller.

In HTML file:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <!-- Opportunity -->
        <!-- Display -->
        <div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large">
            <br />
            <!-- Fields -->
            <lightning-accordion active-section-name="A">
                <lightning-accordion-section name="A" label="Task Details">
                    <div class="slds-grid" style="color:rgb(15, 15, 15); font-size:13px">
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                            <div class=" acc slds-list_horizontal slds-border_bottom">
                                <label>Subject</label>
                                {subject}
                            </div>
                            <div class=" acc slds-list_horizontal slds-border_bottom">
                                <label>Status</label>
                                {status}
                            </div>
                            <div class=" acc slds-list_horizontal slds-border_bottom">
                                <label>Related To Account</label>
                                {relatedtoaccount}
                            </div>
                            <div class="acc slds-border_bottom slds-list_horizontal">
                                <label>Priority</label>
                                {priority}
                            </div>
                            <div class="formfield slds-list_horizontal slds-border_bottom">
                                <label>Assigned To</label>
                                <div class="a11">{assignedto}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-2">
                            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                                <div class="formfield slds-border_bottom slds-list_horizontal">
                                    <label>Due Date</label>
                                    {duedate}
                                </div>
                                <div class="formfield slds-border_bottom slds-list_horizontal">
                                    <label>Type</label>
                                    {type}
                                </div>
                                <div class="formfield slds-border_bottom slds-list_horizontal">
                                    <label>Comments</label>
                                    {comments}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </lightning-accordion-section>
            </lightning-accordion>
        </div>
        <br />
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

In JS file:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getSObjectValue } from '@salesforce/apex';
import GetTaskRecords from '@salesforce/apex/FetchTaskLWCController.GetTaskRecords';
import task_Object from '@salesforce/schema/Task';
import Task_Assigned_To from '@salesforce/schema/Task.OwnerId';
import Task_Status from '@salesforce/schema/Task.Status';
import Task_Priority from '@salesforce/schema/Task.Priority';
import Task_Due_Date from '@salesforce/schema/Task.ActivityDate';
import Task_Type from '@salesforce/schema/Task.Type';
import Task_Related_to_Account from '@salesforce/schema/Task.WhatId';
import Task_Subject from '@salesforce/schema/Task.Subject';
import Task_Comments from '@salesforce/schema/Task.Description';


export default class ApexWireMethodToFunction extends LightningElement {
    @api TaskRecord;
    @api recordId;
    @track tasks;
    @track error;

    taskObject = task_Object;

    @wire(GetTaskRecords, { taskId: '$TaskRecord' })
    task;

    get assignedto() {
        return this.task.data ? getSObjectValue(this.task.data, Task_Assigned_To) : '';
    }
    get status() {
        return this.task.data ? getSObjectValue(this.task.data, Task_Status) : '';
    }
    get priority() {
        return this.task.data ? getSObjectValue(this.task.data, Task_Priority) : '';
    }
    get duedate() {
        return this.task.data ? getSObjectValue(this.task.data, Task_Due_Date) : '';
    }
    get type() {
        return this.task.data ? getSObjectValue(this.task.data, Task_Type) : '';
    }
    get relatedtoaccount() {
        return this.task.data ? getSObjectValue(this.task.data, Task_Related_to_Account) : '';
    }
    get subject() {
        return this.task.data ? getSObjectValue(this.task.data, Task_Subject) : '';
    }
    get comments() {
        return this.task.data ? getSObjectValue(this.task.data, Task_Comments) : '';
    }
}
```

In Apex controller:

```
public with sharing class FetchTaskLWCController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Task GetTaskRecords(Id taskId) 
    {
        Task task = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, Status, Priority, ActivityDate, Type, WhatId, Subject, Description FROM Task WHERE Id =: taskId LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('task'+task);
        return task;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I have mentioned this in my post.

Comment: Yes, right but even then she was not getting results and there must be some little mistake so I refined HTML and JS files along with the apex controller just to make sure she will get her task done now.

Comment: hey @AviRai & rahulgawale, thanks guys for your help. I resolved this issue yesterday itself. there is silly mistake in html file, because of which it is not showing up any value. I did remove that tag and it is now showing expected results. Still thank you so much for help :)

Comment: Great, anyways its always better to specify what steps you follwed or what changes you made to resolve the problem. Which will help other people as well

Answer (score 0):

Your apex method is returning a list of tasks `public static List<Task> GetTaskRecords(){...}`. So the data in the wired method result is a list of objects, not an Object.

As you are working on a single task, you can change the method signature to return a single task like below.

You are also missing to send a task id to the apex method.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Task getTaskRecord(Id taskId){
    return [SELECT Id, OwnerId, Status, Priority, ActivityDate, Type, WhatId, Subject, Description FROM Task WHERE Id = :taskId];
}
```

Js code is like.

```
import getTaskRecord from '@salesforce/apex/FetchTaskLWCController.getTaskRecord';
//..
//... 
@wire(getTaskRecord, { taskId: '$TaskRecord' })
task;
```

Also, it's a good idea to follow naming conventions in your code. See I have changed method name from `GetTaskRecords` to `getTaskRecord`

Comment: i have done same changes, to send task id in method. but not sure why this is still not working. it is still showing me labels, not value of fields.

Comment: @Snehal did you try to debug the apex method and wired method?